# ImageIO: ERROR - MetadataLib.dylib not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, metadata, admob, javax.imageio

I'm getting an odd error in my console when running my app sometimes:

```
ImageIO: ERROR - MetadataLib.dylib not found
```

I'm not sure what this is related to, but I am running AdMobs ads.

Comment: did you found solution to your problem...? I am having the same problem ....

Comment: unfortunately no solution. I have a feeling it is related to the AdMob library. Going to post a bug on their forums.

Comment: I just started noticing this error as well, but I don't use AdMob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, so got a response back from Apple.  Looks like it's a bug in 4.1's SDK that is addressed with 4.2's SDK.  In my code, it was caused by a particular JPEG with a bunch of metadata in it.  Upgrading to the latest SDK should eliminate the issue.